# Finding Laurent Series in annulus $\{2<|z|<3\}$

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

I need help for this question:
Find the Laurent series for $f(z) = \frac{z^3}{3-2z}$  in $A = \{2<|z|<3\} $

I am not sure how to start..
My idea is that, since the annulus is $\{2<|z|<3\}$, I tried to decompose the $f(z)$ to fractions with denominator $({1-\frac{2}{z}})$ and $(1-\frac{z}{3})$ 
However, I can't seem to fit them back into $f(z)$

Or can I find the Laurent series for $f(z)$ in $B = \{\frac{3}{2}<|z|<\infty\}$  and conclude that since the required annulus is a subset of $B$, then the laurent series I got for $B$ is valid for $A$ as well? (by uniqueness of laurent series)

Comment: Please add additional context, specifying exactly what your problem is. Questions that are just copied from a textbook with no context or effort of  your own tend to be  poorly received here.

Comment: Would [hundreds of already-solved](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/laurent-series), near-identical questions be of any help?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: In your case the annulus is $2<|z|<3$. So you can consider $2<|z|$ as $|2/z|<1$ and similarly $|z|<3$ as $|z/3|<1$ and then proceed. Hopes this helps.

Comment: Hello! Thanks for the hints! Actually I considered this method too, but I can't seem to factorize them because the denominator has only one factor..

Answer (score 0):

You had absolutely the right ideas! Unfortunately, the (more obvious) first one didn't work out, but the second was spot on. Since $$f(z)=-\frac{1}{2z}\cdot\frac{z^3}{1-\frac{3}{2z}}=-\frac{z^2}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{1-\frac{3}{2z}},$$ and since $\left|\frac{3}{2z}\right|<1$ if and only if $|z|>\frac32,$ then for all $z$ in the desired (sub)annulus, we have \begin{eqnarray}f(z) &=& -\frac{z^2}{2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{3}{2z}\right)^n\\ &=& -\frac{z^2}{2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{3^n}{2^n}z^{-n}\\ &=& \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{-3^n}{2^{n+1}}z^{2-n}\\ &=& -\frac12z^2-\frac34z-\frac98+\sum_{n=3}^\infty\frac{-3^n}{2^{n+1}}z^{2-n}\\ &=& -\frac12z^2-\frac34z-\frac98+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{-3^{n+2}}{2^{n+3}}z^{-n}.\end{eqnarray}